# PHP to JQuery code conversion [If else]

Tags: php, jquery, html, visibility

How can I do it on JQuery? When I click `hide`, the element will be hidden, same goes for `show`, the element will be shown. How am I going to do it? Thanks!

```
<form method="POST">

<button type="submit" name="hidden" >Hide</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" >Show</button>

</form>

<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['hidden']) == true){
        echo '*hidden*';
    } else if ($_POST['']) {
        echo 'shown';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hide/ show in Jquery click here 


https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: *"When I click hide, the element will be hidden"* - What element? Also, those are submit buttons - do you still want to submit the form, or only show/hide some element? (By the way, this isn't really a "code conversion": your PHP just outputs one string or another, whereas what you want is to hide/show an element.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(input([name='hidden']).click(function(){
      $(this).hide();
   });
    $(input([name='submit']).click(function(){
      $(input([name='hidden']).show();
   });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).show()`? How would the user click the button if it wasn't already visible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use js like this,

```
document.getElementById('domid').style.visibility='hidden';

document.getElementById('domid').style.visibility='visible';
```

Comment: Definitely the best option if this is all you need to do. No need to load jQuery just for this.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent of your code on jQuery would be the next:

```js
$(() => {
    $("#hide-but").on("click", () => $("#result").html("*hidden*"));
    $("#show-but").on("click", () => $("#result").html("shown"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button-group">
  <button type="submit" name="hidden" id="hide-but">Hide</button>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="show-but">Show</button>
</div>

<div id="result">shown</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for JQuery, the best option is straight JS as stated in another post here. But using php, you could define some classes and then change the class value in the tag you wish to control display for upon proper submit of your $_POST value.

```
<?php 

$result = ''; //You could place your default value here or run it through an if/else or switch stmt
if(isset($_POST['show'])){
        $result = 'show';
    } else if ($_POST['hidden']) {
        $result = 'hide';
    } else {
        $result = 'default';
    }

?>

<style>
    .show {
        display:block;
    }
    .hide {
       display:none;
    }
    .default {
       //however you wish your default CSS to act hidden or visible
    }
</style>
<body>
<form method="POST">

<button type="submit" name="hidden" >Hide</button>
<button type="submit" name="show" >Show</button>

</form>

<div id="theElement" class="<?=$result?>"></div>
</body>
```